# I need help accepting a newline from a user input in c

Tags: c

Is there a way in c to accept multiple new lines from a user and print it to screen?

If so would which would be better in attaining that: `fgets` or `scanf` or something completely different?

I'm trying to ask the user to input a home address that can be multiple lines.

Comment: The issue being that when the user presses **Enter** for the next address line, and `'\n'` is generated -- ending the current input (for `fgets()` or `scanf()`). The other option is character oriented input with, e.g. `getchar();` -- but then, while you can process multiple lines, `getchar()` will block when you get to the end wating for the next input until a manual `EOF` is generated with **Ctrl + d** (or **Ctrl + z** on windows). That is a less than elegant solution as well. A better solution is `fgets()` and simply have the user press **Enter** on an empty line when done.

Comment: E.g. `char line[256]; while (fgets(line, sizeof line, stdin) && *line != '\n') { /* handle your address */ }` You will parse anything needed with `sscanf(line, ".."...)` or a pair of pointers. When the user presses **Enter** on an empty line -- the loop ends.

Comment: If you're concerned about newlines, using `scanf()` et al is probably wrong — it is ridiculously hard work to do it right with `scanf()` and there are simpler and more effective tools for the job. How do you know when an address is complete if it is spread over multiple lines? One simple convention would be to treat 'consecutive newlines' — one newline ending a non-empty line and a second newline ending an empty line (or perhaps a line consisting only of white space — blanks and tabs). Other options are possible — e.g. some programs use a line consisting of only a dot `.` (and a newline).